# Change customer attribute position in backend

Tags: magento

I've successfully added Customer Attributes that appear correctly in the backend.
But I cannot change their position.

I've search in the eav_attribute and customer_eav_attribute tables and haven't found any position field which is strange because both at attribute setup and in Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup, it is possible to specify a position in the setup array.

Of course, while setting up my new customer attributes, I correctly gave a position key => value to my new attributes.

Does someone have a clue on how to change customer's attributes position in the backend ? Or the sorting key is unfortunately the attribute_id ?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify this relation in the table eav_entity_attribute.

Comment: Thanks Lucasmus, you rock! BTW, this is still strange to my eyes as both catalog and customer attribute have a [catalog/customer]/eav_attribute table. A 'position' field should be good to have... Maybe this is the case in Magento Editions which can manage customer attributes from the backend. Thanks again.

Comment: This is possibly done to allow multiple attribute configurations on different locations using the same attributes? The attribute tables don't decide where they are positioned, they are just the attributes. eav_entity_attribute takes care of the various configurations. I'm not sure though.

Comment: In my case, I could change the sort order in customer_eav_attribute table (with magento 1.7).